# Listening to reaction or message after sending embed in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command, that should setup the verification process, i want that my bot, after sending an embed, listens for the next message, sent in chat, and storing that message in a variable. I know that `on_message()` exists, but how do to that without it?
The command should look something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def verificationSetup(ctx, channel_id, message):
    if channel_id is not None:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Send the emoji you want to set!", description=" ")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
        emoji = listen_to_message()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

What I was looking for was [`wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Solved thanks to a guy on [discord.py's discord](https://discord.gg/dpy)